# Heuristic For A* Algorithm

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, a-star, heuristics

I have a problem to solve with A* but i'm having difficults to design a good heuristic.

My problem are:

Determine the best route to accomplish by a garbage collection truck in a city that moves on a map known seeking to maximize the load and minimize travel time.

I have 4 types of nodes: Geral Nodes, Dump Nodes, Garbage Nodes and Gas Nodes.

The garbage collection truck may run out of gas and have the chance to refill the vehicle. There may also be more than 1 garbage dumpster where to deliver.

Whats the best heuristic to solve this problem?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

A good first-pass search heuristic is to use a greedy algorithm. For example, in a general route-planning algorithm (find the shortest route between cities) a decent heuristic is to use a greedy algorithm where you always go to the next city that's closest to the destination as the crow flies; this is a linear-time heuristic and never overestimates the solution. In your case, maybe you can use a greedy algorithm in which a garbage truck always goes to the next-closest garbage node, or the garbage node with the most garbage; I can't get more specific without knowing the details of the four nodes you're using, but you get the idea.  Any linear-time algorithm that doesn't overestimate the solution will do, and you can then tweak it in your next pass. (An nlog(n) heuristic is also acceptable in most cases; n^2 is getting awfully expensive.)

Comment: Dump Node, Garbage Node and gas Node are Subclasses of Geral Node. Geral node only have a name, x and y position and a unique id and a node type identifier..a dump node and gas node only differ from geral node on node type. Garbage Nodes have also an trash variable indicating the trash that garbage has...To do this problem i use jgrapht and use WeithedGraph of this library.. I have also a class called truck that saves the maxCapacity, maxGAs and actualGas and actualCapacity of truck.. Any other idea to do this_

Comment: I'm guessing you need to visit a Dump Node when your truck is filled, and you need to visit a Gas Node before you run out of gas. One greedy approach is to visit the next-nearest Garbage Node until your trick is filled (or the next Garbage Node with the most garbage, or whatever), and then make a beeline for a Dump Node; if your truck runs out of gas, go to a Gas Node. This will probably be a crap heuristic; the next step is to weight each Garbage Node according to its proximity to a Dump Node so that you visit the Garbage Node closest to the Dump Node before you visit the Dump Node.

Comment: At some point you'll probably want to weight the Garbage Nodes according to how close they are to a Gas Node, so that you visit the Garbage Node closest to the Gas Node before filling up. And so on. You'll be endlessly tweaking this thing until you're satisfied with it. The rules you need to follow are: the heuristic can't overestimate the solution (which it won't so long as you're using a greedy algorithm), and it needs to be O(n) or O(nlog(n)) (which it will be if you're basing it off of a greedy algorithm)

Comment: Thanks for the answer..I have implemented an heuristic right now but i have another problem..I'm using this implementation of ASTAR https://github.com/narfman0/jgrapht/blob/master/jgrapht-core/src/main/java/org/jgrapht/alg/AStarShortestPath.java but with this implementation i cant update my truck info because the algorithm saves the info in cameFrom map and only build the path when found endVertex..So how i can update capacity of my truck and gas of my truck? I can Reconstruct the intermediate path every iteration and actualize gas with the  current info ...but is the best method to do this?

Comment: How much does it cost to reconstruct the intermediate map?  If it's linear time, then that's probably the way to go.  It might be slightly more efficient to precede each `put` call to cameFrom with an update to the truck, but reconstructing the map sounds less error-prone.

Comment: The algorithms described here ("Greedy algorithm") is according to the book "In pursuit of the traveling salesman" on average 15% worse than optimal on only 48 cities. Given the added constraint complexity and probably data scale of your problem too - even taking into account the smart tweaking tips mentioned above - it's still very likely to result in a very suboptimal route. You could take the result of that algorithm and throw metaheuristics on it to improve it further. In any case, you'll want to avoid that a human looks at the result and can easily improve it.

Answer (score 0):

A* is great to find the fastest/shortest route between 2 points.

However, your garbage truck problem is probably a completely different problem: you need to find the fastest/shortest route by ordering a set of points. That's basically the Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP) or it's big brother the Vehicle Routing Problem (VRP), both of which are **NP-complete**.

**A* cannot handle NP-complete problems**, you need algorithms like **metaheuristics** etc. Look for solutions on the TSP and VRP problems, for example [the TSP and VRP example in OptaPlanner (java, open source)](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#vehicleRouting) (which is shown in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4hp_Qg1hFgE)).

Comment: Really thanks for your answer..Im doing this work for a class of my master in informatics engineering and in the assignment the professor wants that problem will be solved with A*...Until now i cant have the problem solved with g(x) and h(x) that i select. I need more options and sugestions..regards